# Xamarin store information

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin

I am working on a new xamarin based project, where I have to somehow store transaction data, data should not be lost eve if application is shut down. So I decided to store a file with transaction information written, so as program could access the file and read, or rewrite information when needed. Firstly I was thinking of creating asset .txt file, but I found out that it is impossible to write information to this kind of files. Second case is using embedded files, but I still cant get where it should be kept, so as user would not delete it unintentionally. If it is possible share your experience or send an article with explanation on this topic.

Comment: this is traditionally what a database is used for.  There are many articles and samples on using local SQLite db's with Xamarin apps.

Comment: in my case i have to store one string is it worth implementing the database?

Comment: How are you storing all of your transaction data in a single string? There are ways of persisting short strings other than using a database, but I don't know if they'd be appliccable.

Comment: currently I am storing an object of my transaction (4 properties) as JSON string and serialize/deserialize it when needed.

Comment: So you only ever want to store a single transaction with four properties? You could try four entries in Application.Current.Properties then. If you need to store multiple transactions, however, SQLite is the way to go.

Comment: @FraukeNonnenmacher thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store small bits of information in the Application properties like this:

```
string foo = "Foo";
Application.Current.Properties["bar"] = foo;
```

And retrieve them thusly:

```
string foo = Application.Current.Properties["bar"] as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way I found.  This is supposed to be cross platform capable, I have only tested the Android version so far.

Use nuget to install

XAM.Plugins.Settings

to store a value (I have only gotten strings and ints to work)

```
var settings = CrossSettings.Current;
settings.AddOrUpdateValue<string>("key", value);
```

to retrieve value

```
var settings = CrossSettings.Current;
var strSettings = settings.GetValueOrDefault<string>("key", string.Empty);
```

I tried more complex types and got an error

System.ArgumentException: Value of type PreSetStruct is not supported. occurred

PreSetStruct was a simple struct with a few fields.

I will be working on the iOs version later and will let you know how it works.